# What is this number in flag history?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

I was reviewing my flagging history list and i saw a strange number after the question/answer I flagged. Have a look at in the image,

> [image]

Now such type of number is there in few flag posts, while others don't have it. I just want to know is what this number indicates?

Comment: Just hover on it.

Answer (score 8):

That indicates numbers of answer on the flagged question*.

It will not show anything if:

- The flagged question doesn't have any answer.
- The flagged post is an answer.

<sub>(just hover on that number)</sub>